# MVC: VirtualPathProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've already searched here on SO, but I don't find a solutions, so let's hope that somebody of you can provide me some guidance.

I want MVC to load views from the database, therefore I've created a VirtualFile and a VirtualPathProvider.

This is the code from the VirtualFile:

```
public class OxygenVirtualFile : VirtualFile
{
    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    ///     Create a new instance of the <see cref="OxygenVirtualFile"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="virtualPath">The virtual path to the resource represented by this instance.</param>
    /// <param name="body">The contents of the virtual file.</param>
    public OxygenVirtualFile(string virtualPath, string body)
        : base(virtualPath)
    {
        content = body;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the contents of the virtual file.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly string content;

    /// <summary>
    ///     A boolean that indicates wether this virtual file does exists.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Exists
    {
        get { return (content != null); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region VirtualFile Members

    /// <summary>
    ///     returns a read-only stream to the virtual resource.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A read-only stream to the virtual resource.</returns>
    public override Stream Open()
    {
        var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        return new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(content), false);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then I have the provider itself:

```
public class OxygenVirtualPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider
{
    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    ///     Create a new instance of the <see cref="OxygenVirtualPathProvider"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exludedPath">The path that should be excluded and thus not be rendered using this virtual path provider.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     If the specified path does occur somewhere in the url, the view is not rendered using this <see cref="VirtualPathProvider"/>.
    ///     In all the other cases, the view is rendered using this <see cref="VirtualPathProvider"/>.
    /// </remarks>
    public OxygenVirtualPathProvider(string exludedPath)
    {
        var unityContainer = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUnityContainer>();

        unitOfWork = unityContainer.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();

        this.exludedPath = exludedPath;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the <see cref="IUnitOfWork"/> which is used to access the database.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Get the root path of the dynamic views.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly string exludedPath;

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    ///     Check if the view is dynamic view.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="virtualPath">The path of the virtual view.</param>
    /// <returns>True is the view is a dynamic view, false otherwise.</returns>
    public bool IsDynamicView(string virtualPath)
    {
        // If the path which is requested does contain an excluded url, this virtual path provider will not handle this.
        if (virtualPath.ToLower().Contains(exludedPath))
        { return false; }

        var fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(virtualPath);
        var viewExists = DoesViewExistInDataBase(fileNameWithoutExtension);

        return viewExists && !virtualPath.ToLower().Contains(exludedPath);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Verify that the requested view exists in the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="virtualPath">The path of the virtual view.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the view exists in the database, false otherwise.</returns>
    public bool DoesViewExistInDataBase(string virtualPath)
    {
        var fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(virtualPath);

        return new ViewManager(unitOfWork).Exists(fileNameWithoutExtension);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the view from the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="virtualPath">The virtual path of the view to retrieve.</param>
    /// <returns>A string representing the body of the view.</returns>
    public String GetViewBodyFromDb(string virtualPath)
    {
        var fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(virtualPath);

        return new ViewManager(unitOfWork).Get(fileNameWithoutExtension);
    }

    #endregion

    #region VirtualPathProvider Members

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets a value that indicates whether a file exists in the virtual file system.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="virtualPath">The path to the virtual file.</param>
    /// <returns>true if the file exists in the virtual file system; otherwise, false.</returns>
    public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
    {
        return IsDynamicView(virtualPath) || base.FileExists(virtualPath);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets a virtual file from the virtual file system.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="virtualPath">The path to the virtual file.</param>
    /// <returns>A descendent of the <see cref="VirtualFile"/> class that represents a file in the virtual file system.</returns>
    public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
    {
        return IsDynamicView(virtualPath) ? new OxygenVirtualFile(virtualPath, GetViewBodyFromDb(virtualPath)) : base.GetFile(virtualPath);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns a hash of the specified virtual paths.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="virtualPath">The path to the primary virtual resource.</param>
    /// <param name="virtualPathDependencies">An array of paths to other virtual resources required by the primary virtual resource.</param>
    /// <returns>A hash of the specified virtual paths.</returns>
    public override string GetFileHash(string virtualPath, System.Collections.IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies)
    {
        return base.GetFileHash(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Creates a cache dependency based on the specified virtual paths.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="virtualPath">The path to the primary virtual resource.</param>
    /// <param name="virtualPathDependencies">An array of paths to other resources required by the primary virtual resource.</param>
    /// <param name="utcStart">The UTC time at which the virtual resources were read.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="CacheDependency"/> object for the specified virtual resources.</returns>
    public override CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string virtualPath, System.Collections.IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart)
    {
        return Previous.GetCacheDependency(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies, utcStart);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

In order to ensure that my view is inheriting correctly, I do return this:

```
 public string Get(string name)
 {
     return "@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<dynamic>" +
            " <h2>title</h2>";
 }
```

According to me and to what I've found here on SO, this should work, however the following error is throwed:

```
The view at '~/Views/Home/articles.aspx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>.
```

**EDIT:**

The provider is registered in the global.asax file aswell:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new OxygenVirtualPathProvider("/CMS/"));

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Anyone has an idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

I've managed to find a solution.
Mvc was searchinf for ASPX, ASCX, CSHTML and other files.

When I changed my VirtualPathProvider to only load dynamic files when the searched file ends with .CSHTML the error went away.

It's working now, but I would like to know why I has this behaviour in the first place.
Anyone who can provide me an answer on that one?